# Sharepoint 2016 message "Sorry, this list hasnt been shared with you" when accessing from new subnet. Access from existing subnet works fine

Tags: sharepoint-server, restricted-access

I recently configured a new VPN for users in our UK office. This new VPN was created to allow users to access a SharePoint server that is located on an Azure VM. The office has a VPN to the Azure cloud that allows them to access the VM and SharePoint site. After creating the VPN we discovered during testing that any time we would try to access the SharePoint site, we would get the "Sorry, this list hasn't been shared with you." page. But if we connect the same laptop to an existing IP subnet it connects fine with the same user. It appears as if the SharePoint site is restricting access by IP address but I have not been able to find where such a setting would be. The is SharePoint running on a VM in the Azure cloud, it is not SharePoint online.

Comment: SharePoint does not have IP address restriction capability. You'll need to start looking at IIS logs, ULS logs, and potential Fiddler client traces.

Comment: Ok, after locating the IIS logs I noticed that it was detecting my test user I created for the VPN testing to access the SP site, which doesnt have access. I logged on the VPN with my user account and it worked. Thank you